# Azure Data Factory (ADF) can't delete parameters for 'Override template parameters'

Tags: azure-data-factory

In the Devops, I set up the following deployment plan

[image]

However, the 'Override template parameters' automatically added the following parameters which do not exist in ADF and can not be deleted. If I delete the two, it will automatically add back when click 'save'. Anyone knows why?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> parameters specified are not found in template and could fail the deployment

This error might occur when you delete the original parameters but still specify them in the script.

Here, you can see I encountered a similar error in the dataset, where I am using the deleted parameter `tableName`.

[image]

To resolve the error, recheck your script for deleted parameters. Remove the script for those parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did check the pipeline and I couldn't find any parameters which not included in ARM. I also 'Validate' the adf and it passes. Any other suggestions? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you check the similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76317822/main-template-parameter-not-found-error-when-deploying-arm-template-spec)?